# How to get all keys from a JSON-Object as a String array in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON Object which I created from a .json file which looks like the follownig:

```
{
  "key1": {
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
  }
}
```

To generate the JSON-Object I use:

```
JSONObject newJSON = new JSONObject(content);
```

What I want to do, is to generate a String array, which contains all keys of the existing JSONObject, to easily access them.

Comment: Please also provide information on what you have tried so far and what did not work about this, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json String to map convertor,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52799454/json-string-to-map-convertor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSONObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) implements the Map interface, so you can use the same way you'd use for Map to generate the list of keys. In particular, you can use the [`.keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) or [`.entrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) method.

For example (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37180410/309412)):

```
JSONObject jsonObj = ...;
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(jsonObj.keySet());
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `jsonObj.keySet()` gives me an error "Cannot resolve method 'keySet' in 'JSONObject'".

Comment: It much needed solution for me. Thanks @Lie Ryan

Answer (score 1):

```
         You could iterate through the keys.
          JSONObject newUserJSON = new JSONObject(content);
          ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
          String key;

          for (Iterator<String> it = newUserJSON.keys(); it.hasNext(); ) {
             key = it.next();
             keys.add(key);
           }
      And also you need to take care of nested json Object for each key.
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer to this question is already available in another SO thread: [Convert string to JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609306/convert-string-to-json-array/15609365#15609365)

Here's the equivalent for your use case:

```
JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(content);

JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("key1");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```